# Adding Multiple Post Types to Query

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I'm trying to add a 'Lessons' post type to populate the wp-query as well as the pre-existing post type 'Modules. Preferably I would like them to be combined into one query showing the most recent 6 posts. I've only been able to get them showing in 2 different queries thus far.

```
<?php 
//Template Name: Last 6 Modules
remove_action( 'genesis_loop', 'genesis_do_loop' );
add_action( 'genesis_loop', 'ca_show_last_six_modules' );
function ca_show_last_six_modules(){ 
$modules = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type'         => 'module',
   'orderby'            => 'menu_order', 
    'order'                 => 'ASC',
    'status'            => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page'    => 6

));
if ( $modules->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <div class="row">   
        <?php while ( $modules->have_posts() ) : $modules->the_post(); ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/modules', 'loop' ); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    </div>
<?php endif;
}
 genesis(); ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the [`wp_query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Type_Parameters) documentation you will see that it is possible to pass multiple arguments as `post_type`. Like this:

```
'post_type' => array( 'module', 'lessons' )
```